# Restore changes in cpp file after close in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote a lot of code in C++ and save. After that I want only try some example code which I find. So I paste this code in this my project main.cpp file (where I had my code). I try it example code and mistake close this file. After that I open main.cpp file, but I can't undo changes by Ctrl-Z. I wanted only try example code and then I wanted undo changes by Ctrl Z, but my mistake is close file. Is it possible undo changes after close file or restore it?

Comment: You must have done more than just close the file, you must have also saved it?

Comment: No, but I do compilation example code in file. File is save automaticuly in compilation process

Answer (score 4):

Your original code is probably gone for good. However, perhaps this is a good time for you to consider adding a [version control system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138621/best-version-control-for-lone-developer) to your tool set, which will help you avoid this kind of mistake in future, as well as give you a lot of other benefits.

Also, it is not a wise idea to paste example code over your own work in the way that you've done, for exactly the reason you've discovered. Insert a new file into your project, or create a separate project for testing example code. I have a separate Visual Studio solution specifically for this purpose.

EDIT: I say "probably" because I can't rule out all possibility of recovery based on the information you've supplied (e.g. you might have some kind of scheduled backup which caught your previous version). Also, if the code you pasted over it was shorter than your original code, it's possible that some of it still exists as unused data blocks on your hard drive, and might be recoverable, assuming something else hasn't already overwritten them.